# can't install mechanize on my VPS by gem install command

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I tried to install mechanize gem on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 VPS.

After  running   `gem install mechanize` I got:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the documentation for formatting text. Making the content readable helps us help you.

Comment: I can't find the right way to format the text of Linux console information, could you please help me ? Thanks

Comment: Help is available in the editor when entering the text. Simply click the `?` button and navigate to the advanced-help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it prompt me to check mkmf.log for more details, so I tried `find ~/.rvm -name mkmf.log`, and found the mkmf.log file is located under the directory /home/kenshinji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/mkmf.log. then I tried `cat /home/kenshinji/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/mkmf.log`, it showed the following message:
[image]

it indicates that can't find lgmp, so I issued the command `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev`, after libgmp-dev has being installed, then I re-try `gem install mechanize`, done! It works!